# Unable to locate package python3-distutils in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, package-management, software-installation, python3

I am an Ubuntu noob and would like to ask you guys to help.

Currently I'm faced with 2 issues.

1st issue is when I'm trying `mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.8 ENV`, it threw me this error.

```
Error: RuntimeError: failed to query /usr/bin/python3.8 with code 1 err: 
'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File 
"/home/yao1122/.local/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/virtualenv/discovery/py_info.py", line 16, in <module>\n    from 
distutils.command.install import SCHEME_KEYS\nModuleNotFoundError: No module 
named \'distutils.command\'\n'
```

After googling from net, I decide to try install this. `sudo apt-get install python3-distutils`. Then it threw me this error.

```
Error: Unable to locate package python3-distutils
```

I am using ubuntu 16.04. Does anyone know what is the root cause?

Much appreciate your precious time for helping me out and THANK YOU in advance!

Comment: Try it with the original Python 3.5 that came with Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 6):

Ultimately I got it working on 16.04 using a solution I found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810521/how-to-install-python-distutils?newreg=0141466c18b74280a72ea4604941bf1a).

Try to run the following in the terminal:

`sudo apt-get install python-distutils-extra`

Per the user who provided this answer, it would seem that python3-distutils ends up installed as a dependency of distutils-extra, though why this method works where other methods failed for me isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

*python3-distutils* and *python3.8* are in the default Ubuntu 18.04 repositories, so you wouldn't get these errors in Ubuntu 18.04.

---

In Ubuntu 16.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install python3.6
cd ~/Desktop/
wget -c http://launchpadlibrarian.net/449402985/python3-lib2to3_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb
wget -c http://launchpadlibrarian.net/449402975/python3-distutils_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb
sudo apt install ./python3-lib2to3_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb
sudo apt install ./python3-distutils_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb
```

You might need to run `update-alternatives --config python3` after the first three commands to temporarily set python3.6 as the default Python 3.X version in order to install python3-lib2to3. Changing the default Python 3 version will break a lot of applications if you don't immediately change it back to the 16.04 system default Python 3 version after you finish installing python3-lib2to3 and python3-distutils and before you close the terminal. These two packages are also compatible with Python3.8, so after you finish installing them you won't need python3.6 and the ppa:deadsnakes/ppa anymore.

If you updated with a new python (from 3.5 to 3.6), then your `/usr/bin/python3` points to the new python that does not have apt_pkg. Edit `/usr/bin/add-apt-repository`. Change the first line of `/usr/bin/add-apt-repository` from `#! /usr/bin/python3.6` back to `#! /usr/bin/python3`

Comment: I have unmet dependencies.

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-lib2to3 : Depends: python3 (>= 3.6.7-1~) but 3.5.1-3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
` my python3 version is 3.7.7

Comment: When i running this line `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa` , i got this error.
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'` my python version now is 3.6.10

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an easier option:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install python3.6 python3.6-dev python3.6-distutils
```

The deadsnakes packages provide many of the packages you might want for running python.

```
python3.*-venv
python3.*-2to3
python3.*-venv
```

[https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)