# Pycharm -> Failed to create virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, pycharm

I wanted to run my first python file on ubuntu when suddenly this message with no further instructions appeared:

[image: Failed to create virtual env]

As a consequence I have researched what the meaning of the error was. According to the forum this was the most appropriate solution:

[image: discussion]

I have tried it, however the same error message appeared. I also made sure that the location  directory where I created my venv was empty. This is the furthest I have come:

[image: Current selection]

After this the same error message appears with no context how to solve it.

Edit:[image: Error message]

Solution: [Unable to locate package python3-distutils in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239202/unable-to-locate-package-python3-distutils-in-ubuntu-16-04)

First answer from ksharp

Comment: Contact PyCharm support at pycharm-support@jetbrains.com and send them `idea.log` from **Help | Show Log in ...**. Other than that - try creating a venv from the terminal - with e.g. `python3.9 -mvenv ...` - does it work?

Comment: Hi i am new to ubuntu, wanted to know how to detect idea.log, only thing I have found to detect log files was cat /var/log/syslog

Comment: That's PyCharm log, see the top menu (File, Edit, View, ..., Help) on your screenshot - select Help and "Show Log in" option there to open the folder with logs.

Comment: Thank you, i just sent the e-mail. In case you are familiar with the error i have attached it to the question.

Comment: Seems like there is no `distutils` package installed. Try `sudo apt-get install python3.9-distutils`.

Comment: Thank you, it almost worked perfectly I just had to add -extra. I found the solution on a different post >> attached above

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in Linux Mint, the solution which helped me was [found on code2care.org, which I also mentioned here:](https://code2care.org/python/failed-to-create-interpreter-pycharm-error)

> You need to update virtualenv package! Run the below command in CMD or
> Mac/Linux terminal,
>
> ```
> pip upgrade virtualenv
> ```
>
> If you have `pip3`, try the below command,
>
> ```
> pip3 upgrade virtualenv
> ```
>
> If you are using conda, try the below command,
>
> conda install virtualenv

First, I [installed `pip3`](https://askubuntu.com/a/778058/1460940) and then proceeded to `pip3 install virtualenv`.

Comment: I think you might have omitted the `install` portion of the command. e.g.

`pip3 install --upgrade virtualenv`